# Highlight the differences between two strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a (somewhat) working solution which finds values that have been added to a string, but it falls down when values have been removed

```js
function highlightDifferences(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (oldValue === '' || newValue === oldValue) // Just return if the old value is empty or if the two values match
        return newValue;

    var highlightedCharacter = ""; // returnText will be modifed below
    var oldValueArray = oldValue.split('');
    var newValueArray = newValue.split('');
    var returnArray = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < newValue.split('').length; x++) {
        if (oldValueArray[0] !== undefined && oldValueArray[0] === newValueArray[0]) {
            returnArray.push(newValueArray[0]); // add the un-highlighted character to the return array
            oldValueArray.shift();  // if the two characters are the same, drop them and move to the next character for comparison
            newValueArray.shift();  
        }
        else {
            highlightedCharacter = '<span class="highlight">' + newValueArray[0] + '</span>';
            returnArray.push(highlightedCharacter); // add the highlighted character to the return array
            newValueArray.shift(); // remove the unmatched character from the array. oldValueArray is unchanged to compare to the next character in the newValue array
        }
    }

    return returnArray.join('');
}

var oldValue = document.getElementById("oldValue").innerText;
var newValue = document.getElementById("newValue").innerText;
var text = highlightDifferences(newValue,oldValue);
document.getElementById("compared").innerHTML = text;

var oldValue2 = document.getElementById("oldValue2").innerText;
var newValue2 = document.getElementById("newValue2").innerText;

var text = highlightDifferences(newValue2,oldValue2);
document.getElementById("compared2").innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.highlight {
            background-color: #fdff674d;
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
<div><strong>Old:</strong> <span id="oldValue">https://somedomain.info/ac834b89e</span></div>
<div><strong>New:</strong> <span id="newValue">https://55some5domain.i555nfo/ac834b89e</span></div>
<div><strong>Show Added characters: </strong><span id="compared">to be replaced</spanid></div>

<hr />
<div><strong>Old:</strong> <span id="oldValue2">https://somedomain.info/ac834b89e</span></div>
<div><strong>New:</strong> <span id="newValue2">https://55some.i555nfo/ac834b89e</span></div>
<div><strong>Result with removed characters: </strong><span id="compared2">to be replaced</spanid></div>
```

You'll see that the highlighting of the result when characters have been removed is incorrect.
How can I "look ahead" for future matches to detect the removed characters?

Comment: FYI there is a unix program called "diff" that has been around for a long long time. I don't know if this can be integrated into your project the way you'd like it to work, but for comparing two versions of a document, diff is great

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thanks. I found a JS version of that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff I didn't really want to resort to using a package, but it might be worth it to avoid reinventing the wheel

Comment: Nice to hear that you followed up on my suggestion! I myself am using a PHP "diff" port

Comment: re: ... worth it to avoid reinventing ... IMO for professional work, one should always look to use a package before doing it one's self; unless you are working for a company that is selling the software you are developing, software is like a delivery truck - important to the business, but not the business. And like a delivery truck, it has a cost to build or acquire, an expected "lifetime" in which it will be useful, and a cost to maintain along the way. Therefore, if you can use 3rd party with your code stack, "free maintenance" can be a win.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching my method and using this library
https://github.com/liddiard/text-diff instead of the one I linked to in the comment because the project I'm working on is not a TS project, so I needed a JS solution. It works really nicely as you see below.

Red highlights show removed values and green shows additions

[image]